# Find the following number

Tags: pattern

```
9.1 - 03112011
9.5 - 05221960        
8.6 - 03282005  
?.? - 03281964
```

Can you find what should be the left side value for the 4th line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer

> 9.2

How i got it

> Each right side instance is a date of a major earthquake/tsunami 
> The earthquake that hit on 3/28/64 was a magnitude 9.2 earthquake
> Link is [here](https://nctr.pmel.noaa.gov/alaska19640328/) if you want more info.

Comment: It was pretty quick :)

Comment: I have been researching earthquakes recently =p. Thats the only reason i recognized the dates.